# Programmatically adjust Computer Time

Tags: windows, matlab, unix, time, gps

I am getting the GPS time from an external instrument.

I would like to set the windows computer time to that GPS time.

Does anyone know a command to manually change the Computer time ?

PS: It might also be interesting to know for unix machine.

Comment: _Programatically_ **or** _manually_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [system](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) function. Depending on your operating system you'd have to change its arguments. For [windows machine](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Computer-Time-and-Date-Using-the-Command-Prompt) you have to set the date and the time separately:

```
changetime = 'time 6:22:07 AM';
changedate = 'date 11/30/2014';
system(changetime);
system(changedate);
```

Note that:

- Time is in the HH:MM:SS AM/PM format;
- Date is in the MM/DD/YYYY format.

For a [unix machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342854/what-is-the-command-line-statement-for-changing-the-system-clock):

```
changedatetime = 'sudo date 113006222014.07';
system(changedatetime)
```

Where the date is in the MMDDhhmmyyyy.ss format.

Comment: Windows requires `SeSystemtimePrivilege` to set the system date and time. If UAC is enabled you'll have to elevate to run the process as an administrator.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! (How do you force administrator credential? ). I am getting : A required privilege is not held by the client.

Comment: I found this : wi = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
wp = System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(wi);
out = wp.IsInRole(System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);

Comment: It will return the elevated level.